# "in" operator showing functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, vector, operators

in my code I was always doing

```
for(i in vector)...
```

and it always worked, but the problem is that it somehow changed and now my for shows all the values but also the properties, like "remove" that is a function, and it is breaking my whole code.

I don't know why it suddenly changed, because I didn't do anything and I'm getting crazy with this already.

Do you guys know what is happening with my application?

Another thing is that the code only get this problem on my computer.

If I clone my repository again and try it works for while but then starts the problem again.

Thank you.

Comment: `it always worked` - really?, `but the problem is that it somehow changed` - not in the last 15 years it hasn't

Comment: *in* shows all enumerable properties, including those on the `[[Prototype]]` chain. Did something change there?

Comment: JaromandaX if I go to another branch with the same code or run my branch in another computer it works, but my branch in my computer works  for a while and then starts getting this and I don't know why.

Comment: @alanfortlink—if you can't post code here that replicates the issue, how can anyone reasonably help?

Answer (score 0):

The `in` operator has always had this behaviour. Just check that the property exists directly on the object instead of on the `prototype`:

```
for (var i in vector) {
    if (vector.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        // Property exists on object
    }
}
```

That should solve your issues.

Tom

Comment: do you know why the same piece of code works in another branch or another computer?

Comment: I can't help you with that one. The spec defines this as the correct behaviour of the `in` operator. Perhaps you're using a different browser which may explain the difference in output you're seeing, but I feel there's a low chance of that being the case.